# Django: ImportError at / No module named urls

Tags: django, templates, url, view

When following along with an online tutorial, I follow the directions exactly but am getting the error listed below. I can see that the model has been created when I visit the admin, but when I visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/friends/ I get the following error. Do I have to create a friend/urls.py file and define something there? Thank you for your help, and I apologize for being such a noob!

```
ImportError at /friends/
No module named urls
```

My project structure is as follows:

```
atmos_v4/
    atmos_v4/
       init__.py
       settings.py
       urls.py
       wsgi.py
    band/
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        models.py
        urls.py
        views.py
    db.sqlite3
    friend
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        models.py
        views.py
    manage.py
    static/
         css/
             ...
         img/
             ...
         js/
             ...
         media/
             ...
    templates/
             band/
                 band.html
```

My urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView 

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    .
    .
    .
    (r'^friends/$', 'friend.views.FriendsAll'),

)
```

My friend/models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

class Friend(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    date_founded = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

my friend/admin.py file:

```
from friend.models import Friend
from django.contrib import admin

class FriendAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', )
    search_fields = ['title']
```

admin.site.register(Friend, FriendAdmin)

my friend/views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def FriendsAll(request):
    friend = Friend.objects.all().order_by('name')
    context = {'friends':friends}
    return render_to_response('index.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

a portion of my index.html file:

```
<div class="friendList">
        <ul>
            <li>{{ friend }}</li>

        </ul>
    </div><!-- end friend list-->
```

settings.py file:

```
"""
Django settings for atmos_v4 project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'y=3ey3sv8lm1j358(2bgthtx0bzy_cjaxug@2npx029nfs@5i%'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'beer',
    'band',
    'friend',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'atmos_v4.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'atmos_v4.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

from os.path import join

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)

STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_PATH,
)
```

Comment: Is the index rendering?

Comment: Did you add friend to your installed apps?

Comment: @cdvv7788 No the index is not rendering and I did add friend to my installed apps

Comment: if http://locahost:8000/ is not rendering, you have some issue with your project settings. Did you create it with startproject?

Comment: which file is the ImportError coming from?

Comment: @cdvv7788, yes I did. I added the settings.py file above

Comment: @awwester, when I try rendering http://127.0.0.1:8000/, I get ImportError at /
No module named urls, when I try rendering http://127.0.0.1:8000/friends/ I get ImportError at /friends/
No module named urls

Comment: Seems to me like the problem is in `ROOT_URLCONF = 'atmos_v4.urls'`. In your atmos_v4/ folder you have `init__.py` is that a typo or is that the file name? it should be `__init__.py` to be recognized as a python module

Comment: @awwester The init__.py is a typo. It is currently labelled correctly. What should the ROOT_URLCONF be?

Answer (score 0):

Add the Friends module to INSTALLED_APPS in your settings.py